# Modify a char* string in C

Tags: c++, c

I have this:

```
char* original = "html content";
```

And want to insert a new

```
char* mycontent = "newhtmlinsert";
```

into the "original" above just before `</body>` tag in the "original".

My new orginal is now:

```
char* neworiginal = "html content before </body>" + "newhtmlinsert" + "html content after </body>";
```

Basically i want to take a char* orginal and convert it into a char* neworiginal which has the original content plus new content that i added before the `</body>` in the "original html content"

here is the modified code, i still need some help:

```
* original data */
    data = _msg_ptr->buff();
    data_len = _msg_ptr->dataLen();


/*location of </body> in the original */

    char *insert = strstr(data, "</body>");

/*length of the new buffer string */

    int length = strlen(data)+strlen(ad_content);
    newdata =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
    memset(newdata, 0, length);

/*copy the original data upto </body> into newdata*/

    memcpy(newdata,data,insert-data);

/*now add the ad_content */
    strcat(newdata,ad_content);

/*copy the data from </body> to end of original string(data) into newdata */

    memcpy(newdata,data,data_len - ending );
```

how do i implement the the last statement : `memcpy(newdata,data,data_len - ending );`

```
  i  need to copy the remainder of the data from my char* data beginning from an
```

the very end...how do i correctly compute the "ending" parameter in the memcpy?

here is the c++ version using strings

```
char *insert = strstr(_in_mem_msg_ptr->buff(), "</body>");//get pointer to </body>
string ad_data = string(_in_mem_msg_ptr->buff(),insert - _in_mem_msg_ptr->buff()) ;//insert the part of _in_mem_msg_ptr->buff() before the </body>
ad_data.append(ad_content); //add the new html content 
ad_data.append(_in_mem_msg_ptr->buff(),insert- _in_mem_msg_ptr->buff(),_in_mem_msg_ptr->dataLen()); //remainder of _in_mem_msg_ptr->buff() from and including </body> to the end
```

Comment: Is that the exact code you used? Because if that's it, you won't be able to add on to `original` (not enough memory). Use `malloc`.

Comment: Which language, C or C++? Please tag it with only one.

Comment: `C` or `C++` ? It seems you want `C` to me, but could you clarify?

Comment: This would be a lot easier composing with `std::string` and exporting at the end as a `char*`

Comment: If this is C++, you're better off using std::string.

Comment: ...and if you want a C++ answer, please change the title of your question when you remove the `C` tag. While it may be appropriate to tag *some* questions with `C` and `C++`, it is unlikely that any question relating to sting manipulation will be among that select group.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `char* original` is composed by two parts, one starts at 0 while the other (html content after) starts at `x` you can use `strcat` and `memcpy`:

```
int length = strlen(original)+strlen(newcontent)+1;
char *neworiginal = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
memset(neworiginal, 0, length);
memcpy(neworiginal,original,x*sizeof(char));
strcat(neworiginal,newcontent);
strcat(neworiginal,original+x);
```

Comment: -1 Buffer overflow (the NUL terminator doesn't fit in the buffer you allocated).

Comment: Just add +1 to the length and you are fine.. you seem so pedantic :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strcat()` for this problem.

Example =

```
/* strcat example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[80];
  strcpy (str,"these ");
  strcat (str,"strings ");
  strcat (str,"are ");
  strcat (str,"concatenated.");
  puts (str);
  return 0;
}
```

Though you need to check the bounds so you can use the bounds variant of `strncat()`.

```
#include <string.h>

char *strncat(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2, size_t n);
```

Make sure whatever buffer you are appending your string into has enough space to not cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: Of course, this won't work if he doesn't allocate enough memory.

Comment: @Rafe +1 - was thinking the same thing. Better to total the length of the strings and malloc

Comment: @Rafe: Correct, statement added to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't have + operator for char * strings. You need to use std::string, i.e.

```
std::string neworiginal = "html content before </body>";
neworiginal += "newhtlminsert";
neworiginal += "..."
```

Comment: He said he's using C not C++ :D

Comment: @Marino however he did include the C++ tag

Comment: ...which has since been removed

Comment: Yes :) now this is an obsoleted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/), [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) and [other cstring/string.h functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/).

Make sure your `char` arrays are large enough to hold concatenated strings. Like, you may want to do the following:

```
char neworiginal[1024];
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `string.h` function `strcat` will concatenate two strings, however it will fail when there is not enough space for the new string. My solution is to make your own version of `strcat`:

```
char* myStrCat(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    char* result;
    char* itr1;
    char* itr2;

    if (str1 == NULL || str2 == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1));   

    itr1 = result;
    itr2 = (char*)str1;

    while (*itr2 != '\0')
    {
        *itr1 = *itr2;
        itr1++;
        itr2++;
    }

    itr2 = (char*)str2;

    while (*itr2 != '\0')
    {
        *itr1 = *itr2;
        itr1++;
        itr2++;
    }

    *itr1 = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

This is kinda ugly, but it gets the job done :)

Comment: The name of the function is not `strCat`.

Comment: Whoops, I was just recalling from memory... fixed :)

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is exactly 1, guaranteed.

Comment: @Ben yes I know but I just like to make sure that I never forget sizeof when I need it, so I always leave it in

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal results in undefined behavior.

You will need to allocate a target buffer (either as an auto variable or by using `malloc`) that's large enough to hold your final string plus a 0 terminator.

Also, you might want to use `sprintf` to make life a little easier, such as

```
sprintf(result, "%s before %s - %s - %s after %s", original, 
    tag, mycontent, original, tag);
```

Comment: does this sound right to you? i am using c++ strings here
        char *insert = strstr(_in_mem_msg_ptr->buff(), "</body>");//get pointer to </body>
       string ad_data = string(_in_mem_msg_ptr->buff(),insert - _in_mem_msg_ptr->buff()) ;//insert the part of _in_mem_msg_ptr->buff() before the </body>
       ad_data.append(ad_content); //add the new html content 
       ad_data.append(_in_mem_msg_ptr->buff(),insert- _in_mem_msg_ptr->buff(),_in_mem_msg_ptr->dataLen()); //remainder of _in_mem_msg_ptr->buff() from and including </body> to the end