# How to extract a subpart of char*

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify a char* string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668091/modify-a-char-string-in-c)

I have:

```
char* htmlstring = "htmldata"
```

How do I extract:

```
char* htmlstring1 = "htmldata before </body>tag"

char* htmlstring2 ="htmldata after and including</body> tag"
```

Can I use `strstr`? Whats the best approach?

Comment: Are you saying you want to extract `"htmldata"` from `htmlstring1` and/or `htmlstring2`?

Comment: Yes, you can use strstr, but you probably don't want to, for a sufficiently non-trivial HTML dataset. You may want to check other questions for parsing HTML via C++, than "extracting a subpart of char*": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser

Comment: basically want to split the htmldata into two const char* strings

Comment: please edit the question to show exactly what the inputs are and what the output you want is.  As it stands the question is rather confusing.

Comment: This question needs more information or it will be closed.

Answer (score -1):

`strncpy(destination_string, source + start, count)`

It's not really safe, but works. You should wrap it around.